# ASP.NET MVC 5: Inject a repository into an IValidatableObject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I have a class that implements the `IValidatableObject` interface, in order to validate the incoming data introduced by the user. The problem is that in order to validate that data, I need to use a class that implements the data repository pattern, which is in another assembly. Something like this:

```cs
public class SelectedFilteringCriteria : IValidatableObject
{
    private IFiltersRepository _filtersRepository;

    public SelectedFilteringCriteria(IFiltersRepository filtersRepository)
    {
        _filtersRepository = filtersRepository;
    }

    public int? SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        var valueOk = _filtersRepository.GetFilters().Any(
            filter => filter.Value == SelectedValue
        );

        if (!valueOk)
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("Not good :("));
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

The dependency container I'm using is Ninject. I would like to know if there's a way to tell MVC to inject the repository class into the `IValidatableObject` when it's going to be created.

Comment: so what is wrong with the code you posted? Are you looking for how to set up the ninject kernel/binding to make your code possible?

Comment: @GregH I even don't know if it's possible to make it work. Now, the repository class is configured in the `NinjectWebCommon` file and it's working properly when it comes to get injected into controllers, but I can't make it get injected into the class I posted, mostly because I don't instantiate that class, it's MVC which instantiates it with an incoming request. I would like to know how to get it injected into the class I posted.

Comment: It sounds like you may be going about this a little bit the wrong way. I think you want to inject an interface for the repo into the concrete class `SelectedFilteringCriteria` whereas you mentioned trying to inject it into an interface `IValidatableObject`. What is wrong with injecting your repo interface into the concrete class `SelectedFilteringCriteria`? This is how I've seen DI done time and time again. I'm not sure why you'd need to inject anything into an interface itself. Maybe some more context would help

Comment: if you have multiple classes which inherit from `IValidatableObject` and need your repo injected into each of them, then create a base class that your repo interface gets injected into and then have your other class(es) inherit from them. So the class signature would look something like `SelectedFilteringCriteria : BaseCriteria, IValidatableObject` where the repo is injected into `BaseCriteria` so that all classes which inherit from it have access to your repo

Comment: @GregH I didn't say I want to inject a class inside an interface, that's absurd. Ok, in simpler terms: `FiltersRepository` must be injected into `SelectedFilteringCriteria` via constructor. How can I achieve that having into account that it's not me, but MVC what instantiates the `SelectedFilteringCriteria` class. In summary: It's a configuration problem: How can I configure MVC and Ninject to achieve that?

Comment: Well " I would like to know if there's a way to tell MVC to inject the repository class into the IValidatableObject" sure makes it sounds like youre trying to inject something into an interface. Sorry for the confusion. Anyway, Ninject doesn't care who instantiates the class. Take a controller for example. No one is `new`ing up a controller. MVC instantiates it for you and it works the same either way. I think your issue is different than described. I'll go ahead and bow out of this question... good luck

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it seems it's not possible because the `MutableObjectModelBinder` class, which is the one MVC 5 uses to create the corresponding object (`SelectedFilteringCriteria` in my case) from the action parameters, uses `System.Activator` instead of resolving the dependencies `SelectedFilteringCriteria` could have using the current `DependencyResolver`.

A workaround for this could be to do this inside the constructor of `SelectedFilteringCriteria`:

```
public SelectedFilteringCriteria()
{
    _filtersRepository = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IFiltersRepository>();
}
```

But that could drive to the [Service Locator Antipattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). Your choice.